# Why does inline CSS work but not a stylesheet?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have created a web page with uses a stylesheet which has the following class –

```
.div2 {
 border:1px solid black;
 width:75%;
 margin:auto;
}
```

I have applied it to a div tag on the web page like this –

```
<div class="div2"></div>
```

When I view the web page in my browser, the class has no effect at all.
Now, when I use inline CSS like this instead –

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:75%;margin:auto"></div>
```

and view the web page in my browser, the class is applied and works perfectly!

I am glad that it works but I would like to know why it works one way and not the other! Should both methods not result in the same thing happening? I have other classes on the stylesheet which all work so I have not had to use inline CSS anywhere else. Are there any circumstances where inline CSS needs to be used instead of a style sheet? Hope this makes sense!

Comment: You probably have a rule in your stylesheet that supersedes your `.div2` rule. Firebug would tell you if this is the case.

Comment: How are you including the css in your document?

Comment: It is because of specificity conflicts. If you use Chrome, use Inspect element to see the CSS conflict.

Comment: Per @SakhalTurkaystan suggestion, look for `border: 1px solid black;` crossed out. If you see that then look for a `border: ...` rule that is not crossed out to find the CSS rule that is overriding what you want. Get more specific than that rule.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Either your CSS is not loading , or other CSS is overwriting it. Please confirm that you are loading the CSS correctly.

Comment: Also validate your style sheet. If there's an error higher up, it can disable everything that follows.

Comment: make sure your page is referencing to the right style sheet.

Comment: I think the problem was one rule overriding another as @JohnConde said above. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also force CSS rules to be most important

```
.div2 {
 border:1px solid black !important;
 width:75% !important;
 margin:auto !important;
}
```

Use it only temporarily to verify if the class name is typed correctly and if the CSS file is being linked properly.

Comment: Yeppp - adding !important; to the rule in the external css ensures its NOT overwritten elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of interfering with more than one stylesheets. Do check in your header.php or inside head tag, all the stylesheets that you've mentioned. Make sure no two or more stylesheet present with a similar aim.
You can keep minimum stylesheets that are sufficient for your particular project.
Just go to Inspect Element in Chrome and see what styles are applying to your elements.

Even these two stylesheets interfere.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I had the same problem and I've removed `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">` this stylesheet and kept only above one. (Don't forget to save and refresh) External CSS worked fine.